# Writing a code to get a day of the week from any date

Tags: java

so, i made a code for my AP computer science class that is supposed to pull out the day of the week from any date in history, and i *think* i got something that calculates it good, but i'm getting an error message i have never seen before,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

and i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I could just be tired and making a dumb mistake but it would be very helpful if you can tell me what i have done wrong. Here is the original code for reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static int days[] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    static String name[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input month and date(o o to exit)");
        for(;;){
             int m=in.nextInt(), d=in.nextInt();
             if(m==0&&d==0) break;
             System.out.println(solve(m,d));
        }
    }

    static String solve(int month, int date){
        int cur = 3;
        System.out.println("Name of the day:");
        for(int i=0; i<month-1; i++) 
            cur += days[i];
        cur += date-1;
        return name[cur%7];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, highlight line `9` and provide the input used that leads to this exception.

Comment: What input are you inputting?

Comment: How do you expect your program to work?

Comment: Which line is the one where you have your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you provide year along with date and month, your input data is incomplete.  Once you provide all required data, you can create an instance of LocalDate and next 2 lines will do the magic.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 29);
today.getDayOfWeek();
```